# .Marathon-lb has been installed successfully. But dcos has unable to complete Deploy marathon-lb for more than hour

Tags: mesos, mesosphere, dcos

[image: My dcos dashboard]

I installed dcos locally and installed marathon-lb on top of dcos. Installation has been completed but dcos has been unable to complete marathon-lb deployment. It is still either waiting or delayed.

Comment: Can you show your [debugging page](https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.9/monitoring/debugging/gui-debugging/)

Answer (score 0):

At least one node in your cluster needs to be installed with `slave_public`. In node's properties you'll see:

```
public_ip: true
```

`marathon-lb` jobs are supposed to run on nodes with:

```
RESOURCE ROLES: slave_public
```

as you can see from `marathon-lb` configuration page. Such nodes should be facing the internet.

Comment: Thanks Tombart for replying. I have one node which resource_roles is slave_public and public_ip: true

Comment: @EhasanulHoque Is there sufficient memory and CPU on this node (1GB and 2 CPUs)?

Comment: Installed dcos in 32GB/12 CPUs machines with 11 nodes. Only one node has resource roles slave_public. How do I know my that node capacity

Comment: When you go to DC/OS UI (on any master node) `your-master.com/mesos/#/roles` you should be able to see available and allocated resources